# Cannot pass custom prop function through react-router render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have created a PrivateRoute component, in which I have defined a function that I need to pass into components.

```
const validateAuthOnAction = async (linkPropsToPass) => {
  console.log(linkPropsToPass);
  return true;
};
```

And I passed this function to the component through the render method.

```
    return (
      <>
       <Route
         {...props}
         render={() => <Component validateAuthOnAction={validateAuthOnAction} />}
       />
      </>
    );
```

The issue is that I cant access this function from the rendered component. When I try to `console.log(validateAuthOnAction)` it says `undefined`.

Comment: how are you calling `validateAuthOnAction` ? are you passing and argument?

Comment: can u print validateAuthOnAction in this App, not in Component. i wonder something is wrong there.

Comment: Tried printing props on the rendered component. It didn't show `validateAuthOnAction`. I even tried passing a test prop with just a string. This didn't work either.